# Fetch parameters from redirected url in OAuth2 in java

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, redirect, jersey-2.0

I need to use OAuth 2.0 for accessing user's data.
I have used glassfish security oauth 2 library to implement OAuth 2 client.
I am not sure how can I get code and state values after user granted permission to access the data.

```
ClientIdentifier clientIdentifier = new ClientIdentifier(clientId, secret);
    OAuth2CodeGrantFlow.Builder builder = 
OAuth2ClientSupport.authorizationCodeGrantFlowBuilder(clientIdentifier,
            HOST_NAME + "/authorize",
            HOST_NAME + "/token");

    OAuth2CodeGrantFlow flow = builder
            .scope("activity")

            .redirectUri("http://example.com/#/")

            .build();
    String authorizationUri = flow.start();
    System.out.println(authorizationUri);
    String redirectedUrl = getFinalRedirectedUrl(authorizationUri);

    System.out.print("Enter the authorization code: ");
    String code = "";
    String state = "";
    try {
        code = IN.readLine();
        state = IN.readLine();
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    final TokenResult result = flow.finish(code, state);
    System.out.println("Access Token: " + result.getAllProperties());
```

}

For Now, I am taking code and status manually from the redirected url. How Can I automate it.

I tried

```
public static String getFinalRedirectedUrl(String url) {
    String finalRedirectedUrl = url;
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        do {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(finalRedirectedUrl).openConnection();
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode >= 300 && responseCode < 400) {
                String redirectedUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
                if (null == redirectedUrl) {
                    break;
                }
                finalRedirectedUrl = redirectedUrl;
            } else
                break;
        } while (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(finalRedirectedUrl);
    return finalRedirectedUrl;
}
```

but it returns the login page.

Comment: You're supposed to redirect the user the third party login page, they login and authorize your app, then the third-party supposed to redirect the user to your registered redirect URI. This is how OAuth works.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But how can I retrieve parameters from redirected url?

Comment: You need to have a endpoint set up on the server side of the redirect URI and you will somehow have to store the `flow` until the redirect comes. Then you complete the flow.

Comment: With the endpoint you set up for the redirect, you can just use `@QueryParam` to get the parameters from the URL when the third-party redirects to you. Use the parameters to complete the flwo